# Using `malloc` for dynamical array concatenation in C leads to strange exit code

Tags: arrays, c, malloc, dynamic-memory-allocation, function-definition

## Problem statement

I want to write a function

```
int *concat_tab(int n1, int *t1, int n2, int *t2)
```

in pure C which does the following: Given two arrays of integers (as pointers), the function should return a new array which is the concatenation of the two input arrays.

The input names mean the following:

- `n1`: length of the first array;
- `*t1`: pointer to the first element of the first array;
- `n2`: length of the second array;
- `*t2`: pointer to the first element of the second array.

## My code

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int *concat_tab(int n1, int *t1, int n2, int *t2){
    /*
     * Takes two 1D arrays and their lengths as input and outputs their concatenation.
     * Input:
     *  - n1: Length of first array
     *  - t1: First array
     *  - n2: Length of second array
     *  - t2: Second array
     * Output:
     *  - Array of length n1+n2 containing the elements of t1 followed by the elements of t2
     */
    int *output = (int*) malloc(n1+n2);
    for(int k = 0; k < n1+n2; k++){
        if(k < n1) {
            *(output + k) = *(t1 + k);
        }
        else{
            *(output + k) = *(t2+k-n1);
        }
    }
    return output;
}

int main(){
    int array1[4] = {1, 2, 3, 4};
    int array2[5] = {10, 11, 12, 13, 14};
    int *output = concat_tab(4, array1, 5, array2);
    for(int k = 0; k < 9; k++){
        printf("Output[%d] = %d\n", k, *(output+k));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

## My problem

As output I get, as desired,

```
Output[0] = 1
Output[1] = 2
Output[2] = 3
Output[3] = 4
Output[4] = 10
Output[5] = 11
Output[6] = 12
Output[7] = 13
Output[8] = 14
```

However, my program exits with the exit code -1073740940 instead of 0. Why does that happen?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This memory allocation

```
int *output = (int*) malloc(n1+n2);
```

is equivalent to

```
int *output = (int*) malloc( ( n1+n2 ) * sizeof( char ));
```

But you need to allocate memory for objects of the type int.  That is you need to write

```
int *output = (int*) malloc( ( n1+n2 ) * sizeof( int ) );
```

Also the function declaration is bad. Firstly the passed arrays are not being changed within the function. So the corresponding parameters should have the qualifier `const`.

Secondly the parameters that specify the number of elements in the arrays should have the type `size_t`.

Thirdly the order of parameters should be changed.

So the function declaration should look like

```
int * concat_tab( const int *t1, size_t n1, const int *t2, size_t n2 );
```

Pay attention to that you should to check whether the memory was allocated successfully. And you need to free it when the allocated array is not required any more.

Here is shown how your program can look.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int * concat_tab( const int *t1, size_t n1, const int *t2, size_t n2 )
{
    int *output = NULL;

    if (n1 || n2)
    {
        output = malloc( ( n1 + n2 ) * sizeof( int ) );

        if (output != NULL)
        {
            memcpy( output, t1, n1 * sizeof( int ) );
            memcpy( output + n1, t2, n2 * sizeof( int ) );
        }
    }

    return output;
}

int main( void )
{
    int array1[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
    size_t n1 = sizeof( array1 ) / sizeof( *array1 );

    int array2[] = { 10, 11, 12, 13, 14 };
    size_t n2 = sizeof( array2 ) / sizeof( *array2 );

    int *output = concat_tab( array1, n1, array2, n2 );

    if ( output != NULL )
    {
        for (size_t i = 0; i < n1 + n2; i++)
        {
            printf( "Output[%zu] = %d\n", i, *( output + i ) );
        }
    }

    free( output );
}
```

Comment: Thank you! (I am not sure why this answer was downvoted twice.)

Comment: You use `memcpy` to copy the array, right? Would you mind saying a quick sentence about how that works? 

Comment: Also: Why do you first do `int *output = NULL;` ? Is it to check if the memory allocation was successful?

Comment: @MaximilianJanisch The user can pass to the function the values of n1 and n2 equal to 0. In this case there memory shall not be allocated. Otherwise the system can allocate a memory even if the requested size of the extent of memory equal to 0.

Comment: @MaximilianJanisch Using memcpy is more efficient than using for loops.

Comment: I disagree that the order of the parameters has to be changed.  There is a case to be made for using: `int *concat_tab(size_t n1, const int t1[n1], size_t n2, const int t2[n2]);` which keeps the original parameter order but is explicit about the array sizes.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler There is no great sense to declare the function as having variable length arrays because the arrays are adjusted to the type const int *.  So at first should be pointers a(what objects are used) nd then their characteristics. Compare for example with the declaration of the standard string function memcpy or with declarations of other standard string functions.

Answer (score 2):

The undesired exit code happens because the input passed to `malloc` in C denotes the *number of bytes* (which is not, in general, equal to the *length of the array*) that will be allocated in memory (for instance, each `int` in the array requires 4 bytes and not just 1).

Therefore, what happens is that C allocates too little memory for the `output` array. This can be fixed by replacing the line

```
int *output = (int*) malloc(n1+n2);
```

with

```
int *output = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int)*(n1+n2));
```

and now the program will exit as desired.